# Ionic Capacitor Routing provided by Library not working

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

My whole application is built as a Library and with RoutingModules and Page.
I have no problem with my Routing as is. But as soon as i open my Capacitor compiled Application in an Emulator and use change Routes for more than one time i cannot use the Back Button.
When i do so my View crashes, mainly the router outlet and i cannot click on anything in the content of my Application. The only working modules are the ones not provided by my router outlet but in the html

library.components.html

```
<components-header></components-header>

<div [@slide]="getDepth(outlet)">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
<components-footer></components-footer>
<components-loading *ngIf="Loading"></components-loading>
```

library.routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: 'homepage',
        component: HomepageComponent,
        data: { animation: 1 }
    },
    {
        path: 'report',
        component: ReportComponent,
        data: { animation: 2 }
    },
    {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        data: { animation: 4 }
    },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { LibraryModule } from 'my-lib'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        LibraryModule.forRoot(Environment),
        LibraryModule.scan(AppComponent)
    ],
    providers: [
        //File,
        {
            provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
            useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

it makes no difference if i import the RoutingModule directly inside the Application or only in the Library.

Comment: Have you solved this please? I have the exact same problem with Ionic, capacitor app. Navigation works fine in web app but in android or ios the router breaks when going back.

Comment: Edit: I finally managed to get this to work after a lot of hours of searching and trying things by solution mentioned here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22509 or directly in a blog here: https://archive.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/02/cordova-vs-zonejs-or-why-is-angulars-document-event-listener-not-in-a-zone.html. This bug is there from angular version 5.x.x combined either with cordova or capacitor and it carries even to these days :D. Hope it helps someone :)